# Why does `erl_decode` return NULL when deserializing an Elixir map?

Tags: serialization, erlang, elixir

I'm trying to move some data between an Elixir program and a C program. In Elixir, I have a struct of stuff I want to move over. I use `:erlang.term_to_binary` to convert it to a binary that I then mash over to C.

However, when I decode it, it just returns `NULL`?? And there's no error message or anything. A bunch of other elixir/erlang terms work fine; it specifically fails when I try to send over a map or a struct (which is a type of map).

I'm doing something like this in Elixir:

```
  msg = %Message{ title: "hello", body: "world" }
  binmsg = :erlang.term_to_binary(msg)
  send(state.port, {self(), {:command, binmsg}})
```

.. and in C (excluding the receiving of the message, which I have confirmed has arrived with the correct length, and even confirmed that the bytes are identical in C and elixir):

```
  uint8_t *buf = read_cmd();
  ETERM *map = erl_decode(buf);
  erl_print_term(map, stdout);
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems [from the source code of erl_decode](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint-22/lib/erl_interface/src/legacy/erl_marshal.c) that it does not support deserializing maps. Maps ARE [defined in Erlang's binary protocol](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html#map_ext) as of Erlang/OTP 17, but there is no mention of MAP_EXT inside `erl_marshal.c`.

This is likely because `erl_marshal` is hella legacy, and has been deprecated since Erlang/OTP 22. Please use the `ei_decode_*` family of functions instead! There's even a [`ei_decode_map_header`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ei.html#ei_decode_map_header). That should work.